# How can I identify users completely read / viewed all lessons for a particular course in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

How can I identify users who completely read / viewed all lessons for a particular course in Moodle?

I created one course and enrolled 3 users in it, created course have 10 topics, each topic contains some information.

I configured mobile app and connect to it.

I got the course information correctly, but I didn't get any information about users completely viewed all lessons/not.

Moodle provides any options for tracking lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options here. I will provide a few answers on how I monitor my students.

**First:** Enable "Activity Completion" criteria inside your course modules. You can decide if you want a module marked as complete after simply viewing once, spending a set amount of time viewing, reaching the end of the lesson, or achieving a certain grade. You can access these options when editing the settings for a module. Scroll to the bottom to find it.

**Then:** Run various reports inside you course. Logged in as an admin, do the following:

a.) Go to the course you created

b.) In the "Administration" block on the right, expand "Reports"

c.) Look through them all - the ones I think you will find interesting are "Course completion" and "Activity completion"

Beyond that, you can also view the individual progress of each student by looking in the "Navigation" block under "participants".

If you'd like to go even further, you can create very nice custom reports using this Moodle add on: https://moodle.org/plugins/block_configurable_reports

Note: When you configure the "Activity Completion" options of a course, Moodle will not immediately update the status based on what students have already done. This happens as part of the Moodle scheduled tasks that you need to configure to run automatically. I have mine run every hour on a Linux host by doing the following:

```
# set up moodle tasks to run automatically
sudo echo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php  > /etc/cron.hourly/moodletasks.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/moodletasks.sh
```

The above will create a schedule tasks for all of your housekeeping items, like updating Activity Completion. It will run every hour, but you can run it manually when testing as well.

I hope this helps, have fun with Moodle!

Comment: Hi Chris, followed your instructions Enabled activity completion and checked course report section. Accessed all lessons through mobile App, but the report shows no one is viewing the topics, do you know what's the reason for that. Also any Apis available for the viewed status . Thanks

Comment: Did you run the moodle scheduled tasks successfully? This is when it goes through and calculates activity completion status. You'll need to run this before you see any results. You can also just run this on the command line once, but make sure to schedule it in cron for later: `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php`

Comment: Just one additional note: In the scheduled tasks, you'll want to make sure that directory path is correct. It could be different on your server.

Comment: I tried all the settings mentioned in the activity tracking settings section, and checked mobile app, displayed option for close the lesson manually,after click on the button ,  now it shows user read the lesson status.But i couldn't find any option for change the status for completely read the lesson. how to notice that user completely viewed the particular lesson

Comment: Hi Varun - you will not be able to view activity completion until you run the scheduled tasks. You need to find the cron.php script and make sure it is run on your server. I am not talking about something you do in your web browser, but something you will run on the server itself. Do you have administrative access to the server it is running on? What operating system is it and what web server are you using?

Comment: You can find detailed instructions here: https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Cron

Comment: Hi Chris,  i am using windows 10 + Apache server (wamp server) .

Comment: I am updated cron settings via admin side and access cron.php file through a browser, 
successfully executed cron and the corresponding status updated for each course lesson.
Thanks Chris for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Excellent! I'm very glad to hear this worked! Would you mind marking the answer above as accepted? Thanks!